# Remove vertical line in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Where can I find the settings to remove the Vertical Line in the Eclipse editor?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

that's the margin line just change the editor settings

General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show Print Margin

Comment: why should enable it by default ?!

Answer (score 15):

You can do it by navigating to:

### This is for windows

> windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> uncheck Show Print Margin

Also, check out the image below:

[image]

Comment: Note that on macOS the Preferences are in the "Eclipse" menu, not "Windows"

Comment: This is the answer for me on latest version of Eclipse IDE on Windows 10 as of 7/2021.